# Problem finding the plane passing through 3 points

Tags: geometry, vectors

What if solving this problem...

[image]

...I take the 3 vectors difference in this graph

[image]

By imposing that parallelepiped volume is zero, I would get

[image]

And so

[image]

But this, full of variables squared and cubed doesn't look at all a plane! What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing went wrong, just use elementary row operations !  Subtract the first row from the second and third, to recover the form stated in the book
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{vmatrix}
x-x_1 & y-y_1 & z-z_1  \\ 
x-x_2 & y-y_2 & z-z_2  \\ 
x-x_3 & y-y_3 & z-z_3  \\ 
\end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
x-x_1 & y-y_1 & z-z_1  \\ 
x_1-x_2 & y_1-y_2 & z_1-z_2  \\ 
x_1-x_3 & y_1-y_3 & z_1-z_3  \\ 
\end{vmatrix} =0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you. And after all I can also choose not to follow your suggestion and go on: I get an f (x, y, z) = 0 absolutely right for a plan. Why I thought the opposite?